# Is there a direct way to get a node's neighbors?

Tags: cytoscape-web

Is there a direct way to get all network neighbors of a node `n0` in Cytoscape.js?

The best solution that has occurred to me so far is to get all edges where `n0` is the source and all edges where `n0` is the target -- and then look at those edges' targets and sources, respectively.

Is there a more convenient way, say something like a function `cy.nodes("#n0").neighbors()`?

The reason I need this is that I would like to implement a function that removes a node `n0`, but also other nodes that have no edges after removing `n0` should be removed.  Ideas on this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node.neighborhood()` also includes edges, so you can use `node.neighborhood('node')` or any other selector if you want to filter the neighbourhood.

Edit: You can also use degree to do what you want.

`var otherNodesToDelete = node.neighborhood('node{degree = 1}');`

Or you can do `node.remove()` and then do `cy.$('node{degree = 0}')` to look for disconnected nodes.